# I want to know the last time my form was submitted

Tags: php

I have a code where i us `filemtime` to see the time when the textfile was modified.

```
$currentmodif=filemtime($filename);
```

I need to change this line so that I get the time a form was submited. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you store the data, when your form was submitted last in db ?

Comment: when was the form last submitted or when was the data last updated?

Comment: Why don't you call a function that would return the time of submit using `onsubmit`

Comment: Sorry, but this is stupid question. As an IT you should ask yourself what do I have and what do I want to have. Maybe insert into db a row when was $_POST sent?

Comment: I personally think you need to capture the form submission into a database with a timestamp field. If you rely on the file system, an external process or someone reading the file on the disk could modify the file without you knowing and the time the file was last modified would no longer be of value to you.

Comment: Create a submit_time field in the table where this form's data is submitted. In that field store the time when a new record is inserted using NOW().

Comment: Post the code for the form / form handler

Comment: Can we not call a function that would return current time using onSubmit ??? Anyone pls reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the timestamp into database every time when you submit the form. so then by using the select query on database you can get the your result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
<form action="insert.php" method="post" name="input">
<label for="user">Username:</label><input type="text" name="user" />
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?= $date ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
$user = $_POST["name"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
?>
```